# VBA Save as CSV is garbling my data types

Tags: vba, excel, csv

having a bit of an infuriating time dealing with Excel 2013 and I can't seem to find any answers which give me what I need.

I've written some simple VBA which generates a number of dummy data tables, the output is generating absolutely fine, and the formats appear to be correct in the output table prior to export.

However, the element that I'm having difficulty with is when I export the files using VBA into CSV (they need to be uploaded into SQL Server). The export itself works fine, but when I try to re-open the file in Excel the data types in my date columns are 'garbled'. I'm in the UK, and computer is set up as such, but Excel appears to be converting these to a US format, meaning that some are 'date' (any string which would fit a UK format), others are 'general' which would obviously cause issues when uploading to SQL Server.

I've tried manually copying the data tabs, and saving them as CSV. When I do this, I can open them and the date format is absolutely fine. I can only assume therefore that it's something to do with my export, any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Code is as below:

```
Sub exportdata()
wdir = ThisWorkbook.Path
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Save sheets which aren't the command sheet.

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        If sht.Name <> "Command" Then

            Application.StatusBar = "Exporting sheet " & sht.Name
            sht.Copy
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs wdir & "\Generated\" & sht.Name & ".csv", xlCSVWindows
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

        End If

    Next

Application.StatusBar = ""
```

Does anybody have any ideas? Appreciate I can just manually export each tab, but that's incredibly annoying and I'll be needing to run this quite a few times.

Note - I've tried using xlCsv and xlCsvWindows, and the same thing happens.

Comment: Try re-opening the CSV file in Notepad and check if the data is correct, as Excel tends to garble CSVs when opening them, specially dates..

Comment: Have tried opening the file in notepad, and the dates look like the format is changed there. Once again - when I manually export it, this issue doesn't come up. I don't like working with excel where possible for reasons like this, but it's unavoidable here. 

I haven't tried importing, as if the data is being garbled i would have thought that would be the case regardless of which program I use.

Comment: Excel is very international, local so to speak. VBA is 100% American. What are your dates? Basically, if your dates are strings, like "12/1/2018" VBA would be tempted to convert this to December 1, 2018, and failing in some combinations. If your dates are true dates, like 43112 representing 12/1/2018, there should be no chance of confusion. I suspect, however, that you would have to convert your dates to true strings because SQL is unlikely to understand 43112, either.

Comment: I'm using the numeric formats, and the CSV output is converting them to dates, so they appear as date strings in the CSV when I open in notepad (whether I do this manually or in VBA doesn't matter).  

The thing which is *really* confusing me is that the VBA save is evidently what's messing it up. When I do the save manually, there's literally no issue, it only seems to change the formats to US dates when I save as using VBA >.<

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.

The only way I know to avoid this is to open Excel and open the file from Excel.
When the file is opened a screen is popping up and Excel wants to know from the user how the data needs to be opened.

What I usually do is in the 3 screen to select all column and define them as text. This also prevents you from losing leading zero's (if applicable). This way in Excel numbers are as text (you can't calculate with them, but SAP for example doesn't mind to upload numbers as text. :) )

Answer (score 0):

How about looping through your date range before saving as CSV, such as below:

```
Sub exportdata()
Dim c As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
wdir = ThisWorkbook.Path
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Save sheets which aren't the command sheet.

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        If sht.Name <> "Command" Then
            LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            'get the last row with data on Column A
            For Each c In sht.Range("A1:A" & LastRow) 'loop through column A to format dates
              c.Value = Format(c, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            Next c
            Application.StatusBar = "Exporting sheet " & sht.Name
            'sht.Copy
             Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs wdir & "\Generated\" & sht.Name & ".csv", xlCSVWindows
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

        End If
    Next

Application.StatusBar = ""
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will work (and can't test it because I live in the US), but one idea is to Copy/PasteSpecial the values in each sheet rather than copying the sheets directly.

```
Sub exportData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Not ws.Name = "Command" Then
            Application.StatusBar = "Exporting sheet " & ws.Name
            Call createTextFile(ws.UsedRange, ws.Parent.Path & "\Generated\", ws.Name & ".csv", xlCSV)
        End If
    Next

    Application.StatusBar = ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
Sub createTextFile(sourceRng As Range, fPath As String, fName As String, fFormat As Variant)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    sourceRng.Copy
    With wb.Sheets(1)
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(sourceRng.Rows.Count, sourceRng.Columns.Count)).PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    wb.SaveAs Filename:=fPath & fName, FileFormat:=fFormat
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

If that doesn't work, I'd be curious to see if the issue is only with files with the .csv extension; you could test a .txt file by changing this line:

```
Call createTextFile(ws.UsedRange, ws.Parent.Path & "\Generated\", ws.Name & ".csv", xlCSV)
```

To this one:

```
Call createTextFile(ws.UsedRange, ws.Parent.Path & "\Generated\", ws.Name & ".txt", xlText)
```

As a last resort, you may be able to separate the day/month/year into separate columns, then modify your SQL script to combine them as it updates the tables. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptbl
(
    dtyear int,
    dtmonth int,
    dtday int,
    dtdate AS (DATEFROMPARTS(dtyear, dtmonth, dtday)),
    empid varchar(8),
    hrsworked int
);

BULK INSERT #temptbl
FROM '\\yourpath\uploadfile.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);

MERGE dbo.emphours AS target
USING #temptbl AS source
ON
    (target.empid = source.empid) AND
    (target.dtdate = source.dtdate)
WHEN MATCHED AND (target.hrsworked <> source.hrsworked) THEN
    UPDATE SET
        target.hrsworked = source.hrsworked
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN
    INSERT
        (dtdate,empid,hrsworked)
    VALUES
        (source.dtdate,source.empid,source.hrsworked);
DROP TABLE #tempHH;
```